# Switch form to Modal after it is open?

Tags: vb.net

If I have a form open already that is not modal, can I turn it modal by the click of a button on that form.

Comment: I’m curious where you would need this. I can’t think of a use case.

Comment: I have a form for displaying and edit personal information that is stored in a database. It has 2 panels on it, one setup for 'Viewing' and one setup for 'Editing' and theres an Edit button that switches the view to Edit Mode I wanted it to then make the form modal, so they had to finish editing before moving on within the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't suppose so. Usually you have to give the old form as a parameter in the constructor to create a modal form. The .Modal property is also read-only, so from my experience you have to indicate when creating the form.